# VirtualizingStackPanel CanVerticallyScroll Property

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am playing with layout for Windows 8 Store Application and noticed that `VirtualizingStackPanel.CanVerticallyScroll` Property crash my application, but this property should work by [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.canverticallyscroll(v=vs.110).aspx).
[image]

It is strange, even Visual Studio Renders it correctly:
[image]

My code of XAML:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="App5.GroupedItemsPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App5"
    xmlns:data="using:App5.Data"
    xmlns:common="using:App5.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Items}"
            IsSourceGrouped="false"
            ItemsPath="Items"
            d:Source="{Binding Items, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:DataGroup, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" CanVerticallyScroll="False"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

What I want to achieve: Gridview does not have any groups and items stand in 2-3 rows with scroll to the right.

```
------------
|1|4|7|10|
------------
|2|5|8|11|
------------
|3|6|9|12|
------------
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer or an explanation, but if you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel), that property isn't meant to be set in XAML. It does show in intellisense, but if you build, it will indicate the property can't be found.

Comment: @JimO'Neil can you recommend any way to achieve what I described in last part

Comment: doesn't just a WrapGrid versus VirtualizingStackPanel accomplish what you want?

Comment: @JimO'Neil can you please give an example code? Thank you

Comment: just replace <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" CanVerticallyScroll="False"/>
 with <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" /> and see how close that gets you

Comment: thank you! Already solved it, but still, thanks!